# how to configure logging directory

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

We are trying out spring-cloud-dataflow to deploy our microservices in a development environment. Each app logs to the /tmp directory and users the /tmp directory as the working directory.

This blows out the woeful disk space we have available on the machine. Is there any way to configure this?

I have changed spring clouds dataflow so that it's log is moved, and looked in /etc/init.d/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-local but can't see anything to help.

Answer (score 2):

The local deployer has a property `deployer.local.working-directories-root` that can be used to set the log root directory.

Unfortunately, this config property doesn't seem to work now. Please see https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer/issues/112 for tracking this. Once this is fixed, you can set `deployer.local.working-directories-root` for the local deployer.

Comment: The issue is now fixed. You can give it a try using snapshot.